# Magento 2 site optimization module and extensions needed. Paid or Free, any suggestions? SIte is around 64% optimized

Tags: magento2.3

I have a magento 2.3 website i want to optimize it for best performance. Can anyone suggest some good extension or modules which actually gives good performance?

Answer (score 0):

you are looking into wrong direction, best practice is to remove modules, and strip off all the extra from theme.

customers dont need all the bloated functionality.

this what makes magento 2 slow:

> https://github.com/magenx/Magento-2-server-installation/blob/master/composer_replace

if you run this to check how many waste you have. modules you dont use, but magento still using even disabled modules and some settings interefere with frontend loading.

> bin/magento module:status --enabled

so somitemes you need to remove modules completely:

> bin/magento module:uninstall *MODULE_NAME*

all you need is to enable settings in magento admin panel, related to CSS and Javascript,
there is no need to load anything more, these settings already good to speedup magento interface.

if you really like to experiment you can install pagespeed webserver module, to optimize everything before magento:

> https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module

Answer (score 0):

Before installing any site optimization module you need to follow some steps so it will increase site performance easily.

Please follow the below steps for site optimization.

1. **Disable Use Flat Catalog Category and Use Flat Catalog Product options.**
   ==> Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Storefront -> Use Flat Catalog Category && Use Flat Catalog Product -> No -> Save Config.
2. **Enable JS Bundling**
   ==> Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> JavaScript Settings -> Enable JavaScript Bundling -> Yes -> Save Config.
3. **Inspect Third-Party Extensions**
   ==> Remove unused module from the site.
4. **Minify CSS and JavaScript**
   ==> Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Minify JavaScript Files && Minify CSS Files -> Yes -> Save Config.
   After that Flush Cache on System -> Cache Management -> Flush Magento Cache.
5. **Enable GZIP Compression**
   Note : You can Enable GZIP Compression using .htaccess file.
6. **Integrate Content Delivery Network**
   ==> Go to Store -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Base URLs -> Base URL for Static View Files -> Base URL for User Media Files -> Save Config.

   1. On the Base URL for Static View Files field, enter the URL of CDN where static view files are stored.
   2. In the Base URL for User Media Files field, enter the URL of CDN where JavaScript files.
      When complete, click Save Config.
7. **Enable Elastic Search**
   ==> Go to Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Catalog → Catalog → Catalog Search -> Search Engine -> Elasticsearch -> Save config.
8. **Implement Varnish Cache**
   ==> Go to Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Full Page Cache -> Caching Application -> Varnish Caching -> Varnish Configuration -> Configure details -> Save config.
9. **Clean Database Logs **

Note : Set particular time on New Messages Lifetime to automatically clean the old log files.
==> Stores -> Configuration Advanced -> System -> MySQL Message Queue Cleanup -> New Messages Lifetime -> Save Config.

10. Re-index Products on Your Store
    Note : Please reindex using command line.
11. Optimize Product Images
    Note : Large images size is impacts on site speed That's why you need to ensure your images are properly optimized and have a good ratio between quality and size.

After all the changes are done go to on **production mode**.